# How can I hide the Grouped/Stacked button on rnvd3 bar chart in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, nvd3.js, shinydashboard

I would like to hide the button that shows the option of Grouped or Stacked barchart on shiny.

The button should disapear.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code followed by image details

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- navbarPage(title = "Information", 

                 tabPanel(title = "Graph",  

                                   fluidRow(
                                     column(2),
                                     column(8,
                                            tags$br(),
                                            tags$h5("Chart", style="font-weight: bold; font-size:20px", align = "center"),
                                            tags$br())
                                   ),

                                  fluidRow(
                                    column(1),
                                    column(8,
                                           tags$br(),
                                           tags$h5("Exemple", style="font-weight: bold; font-size:14px", align = "center"),
                                           tags$br(),
                                           showOutput("bar","nvd3")), 
                                    column(1)
                                  ),

                          tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                                           .nvtooltip h3 {
                                                    font-size:8px;
                                                    }
                                                    ")))


                 )
)

server <- function(input,output, session) { 

output$bar <- renderChart2({

      database2 <- cbind(cbind(c(100,110,140),c("2016-09-05","2016-09-05","2016-09-05")),c("Product A","Product B","Product C"))
      database2[,1] <- as.numeric(database2[,1]) 
      database2[,2] <- as.Date(database2[,2],origin="1899-12-30")
      colnames(database2) <- c("Price","Date","Key")
      database2 <- as.data.frame(database2)

      m1net_eb <- nPlot(Price ~ Date, group = 'Key', data = database2, type='multiBarChart')
      m1net_eb$chart(margin = list(left=60,bottom=110,right=60))
      m1net_eb$chart(forceY = 0)
      m1net_eb$set(lineWidth = 1, width=1100 , height = 700)
      m1net_eb

})

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS to hide it. Just add these to your current `tags$head(tags$style())` section:

```
.nv-controlsWrap {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make is Grouped  and Hide Controls

```
var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart().stacked(false).showControls(false);
```

To make is stacked and Hide Controls

```
var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart().stacked(true).showControls(false);
```